# I cant upload a file to my '/tmp/' directory with python cgi

Tags: python, html, file-upload

When I try to Upload an image file to the '\tmp\' directory via my python cgi script below,

```
#!c:/Python/python.exe -u

import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get filename here.
fileitem = form['filename']

# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:
   # strip leading path from file name to avoid 
   # directory traversal attacks
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   open('/tmp/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())

   message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'

else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'

print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html>
<body>
   <p>%s</p>
</body>
</html>
""" % (message,)

It gives me this error:

<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/(_)Mr@_--Soft_3Ovo(_)?.jpg' 
      args = (2, 'No such file or directory') 
      errno = 2 
      filename = '/tmp/(_)Mr@_--Soft_3Ovo(_)?.jpg' 
      message = '' 
      strerror = 'No such file or directory
```

'

Below is my HTML Code for selecting a file to upload, I am certain there is no error but i dont know why its not working.:

```
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save_file.py" method="post">
<p>File: <input type="file" name="filename" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitize your filename. Do not trust on user input for that.
You should read the directory traversal section of http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter20.html ,and maybe also the other parts.